# Eclipsify Play Framework Scala project on OSX 10.7

Tags: scala, eclipse-plugin, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am getting the following output form command line when I try to eclipsify the Scala sample form app.

```
 Williams-MacBook-Pro:forms wfbarksdale$ pwd
 /Applications/play-2.0-RC4/samples/scala/forms
 Williams-MacBook-Pro:forms wfbarksdale$ play eclipsify forms
 [info] Loading project definition from /Applications/play-2.0-RC4/samples/scala/forms/project
 [info] Set current project to forms (in build file:/Applications/play-2.0-RC4/samples/scala/forms/)
 [info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
 [info] Successfully created Eclipse project files for project(s): forms
 [error] Not a valid command: forms
 [error] Expected '/'
 [error] Not a valid configuration: forms
 [error] Not a valid key: forms (similar: fork, streams, sources)
 [error] forms
 [error]      ^
```

Had the same problem trying to eclipsify the boilerplate app, has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within the forms directory `play eclipsify` should be sufficient